# Select all the last dates from all list of id

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to select all the videos that were last inserted, without repeating any ID_video_type (id_video_tipo column).

Here's an example of the data int the database:

[image]

I'm trying to run the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM `video` 
GROUP BY id_video_tipo
ORDER BY data DESC
```

but when I do that I get the following result

[image]

As you can see, I managed to get the videos to show up without the `id_video_tipo` repeating, but I can't get the video with the latest date to show up. For example, for `id_video_tipo = 6` it should have shown video with id = 3. Instead, it shows video with id = 2. How can I fix it?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @user13227454 . . . What if multiple rows have the same video type and the same last insert time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause which returns the last date for each `id_video_tipo`:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM `video` v
WHERE v.data = (SELECT MAX(data) FROM `video` WHERE id_video_tipo = v.id_video_tipo)
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM `video` v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM `video`
  WHERE id_video_tipo = v.id_video_tipo AND data > v.data
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to use a [WINDOW function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE video
(
id_video_tipo INT,
data DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO video VALUES (1,'2020-01-01'),(1,'2020-01-02'),(1,'2020-01-03'),(1,'2020-01-04');

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_video_tipo ORDER BY data DESC) AS 'RNum'
    FROM `video` 
) vids
WHERE vids.RNum = 1;
```

The above defintely works in MySQL 8 and above.

Comment: don't function.... Comando SQL: Documentação


SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_video_tipo ORDER BY data DESC) AS 'RNum'
    FROM `video` 
) vids
WHERE vids.RNum = 1 LIMIT 0, 25
Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '(PARTITION BY id_video_tipo ORDER BY data DESC) AS 'RNum'
    FROM `video`
) ' na linha 4

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery is the right approach.  But, if you want to guarantee *one* row in the result set for each `id_video_tipo` -- which your question **explicitly** states -- then you need to be careful.  Duplicates in the source data and result in duplicates in the result set.

The solution to this is to use the `id` column:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM video v
WHERE v.id = (SELECT v2.id
              FROM video v2
              WHERE v2.id_video_tipo = v.id_video_tipo
              ORDER BY v2.data DESC
              LIMIT 1
             );
```

In MySQL 8+, you would use `row_number()` for this purpose, as Jim Jonson suggests.

Comment: . . . You should limit the sub-query to return multi rows.

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . Sigh.  Thank you.